# sometime all knockout js files can't initialize in magento 2 (examp: Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart, ....)

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, magento2.4.5

I'm using magento community-edition ver 2.4.5

When I reload the page many times(any pages), there will come a time be all knockout js files not initialize, it doesn't run into `initialize` function.
[image]

and mini cart not working.

Any ideal welcome.